# toastr message box appears but without text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, toastr

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        Command: toastr["success"]("My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die!")
    });
</script>
```

The box shows up but it is blank and has no text in it.  How do I fix this?  I've tried adding the following above command:

```
    toastr.options = {
      "closeButton": true,
      "debug": false,
      "newestOnTop": false,
      "progressBar": false,
      "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
      "preventDuplicates": false,
      "onclick": null,
      "showDuration": "300",
      "hideDuration": "1000",
      "timeOut": "5000",
      "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
      "showEasing": "swing",
      "hideEasing": "linear",
      "showMethod": "fadeIn",
      "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
```

but all it does is center the box.  How do I get text to appear?

Comment: remove the `Command:` part

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but the text is still not showing

Comment: you getting any error?

Comment: none.  Nothing is showing in the console if i inspect element.

Comment: If you remove command your code is totally fine, please ensure that your code is running after jquery and toastr.js is loaded http://jsfiddle.net/noubazzs/

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `Command:` block.